# Concatenate two dataframes, with some overlaping date index, with resulting dataframe taking "left" as default, except the "left" is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, overlap

Giving DF1 and DF2 below, how to get DFresult?

```
DF1:                        DF2:                        DFresult:       
Date | Value                Date | Value                Date | Value
------------                ------------                ------------
1-01-2019 | 1                                           1-01-2019 | 1       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
1-02-2019 | 1                                           1-02-2019 | 1       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
1-03-2019 | np.NaN          1-03-2019 | 2               1-03-2019 | 2       (left is NaN, take right)
1-04-2019 | 1               1-04-2019 | np.NaN          1-04-2019 | 1       (left is not NaN, take left)
1-05-2019 | np.NaN          1-05-2019 | np.NaN          1-05-2019 | np.NaN  (both NaN, keep it)
1-06-2019 | 1               1-06-2019 | 2               1-06-2019 | 1       (left is not NaN, take left)
                            1-07-2019 | 2               1-07-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
                            1-08-2019 | 2               1-08-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
                            1-09-2019 | 2               1-09-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
                            1-10-2019 | 2               1-10-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
                            1-11-2019 | 2               1-11-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
```

What if I'd like to use a function to determine the overlaping decision? Example, take left if left is higher than right, or if left is NaN:

```
DF1:                        DF2:                        DFresult:       
Date | Value                Date | Value                Date | Value
------------                ------------                ------------
1-01-2019 | 1                                           1-01-2019 | 1       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
1-02-2019 | 1                                           1-02-2019 | 1       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
1-03-2019 | np.NaN          1-03-2019 | 2               1-03-2019 | 2       (left is NaN, take right)
1-04-2019 | 1               1-04-2019 | np.NaN          1-04-2019 | 1       (right is NaN, take left)
1-05-2019 | np.NaN          1-05-2019 | np.NaN          1-05-2019 | np.NaN  (both NaN, keep it)
1-06-2019 | 1               1-06-2019 | 2               1-06-2019 | 2       (left is not higher, take right)
1-06-2019 | 3               1-07-2019 | 2               1-07-2019 | 3       (left is higher, take left)
1-06-2019 | 1               1-08-2019 | 2               1-08-2019 | 2       (left is not higher, take right)
                            1-09-2019 | 2               1-09-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
                            1-10-2019 | 2               1-10-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
                            1-11-2019 | 2               1-11-2019 | 2       (no overlap, take the one that exists)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
out = pd.concat([DF1,DF2]).groupby('Date',as_index=False).max()
# for your original one 

#out = pd.concat([DF1,DF2]).groupby('Date',as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: nice, thanks! What if the condition is not "max()" nor "first" but something like if DF1 - DF2 > 4 ?